# Vue Unit Test Resize Screen and Update DOM

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I have a component that displays an image if the screen is desktop and it hides the image if the screen is for mobile devices:

```html
<script>
export default {
  name: 'MyComponentApp',
}
</script>
<template>
  <div class="my-component">
    <div class="my-component__image-container">
      <img class="my-component__image-container--img" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.my-component {
  &__image-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 50%;
    &--img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      object-fit: cover;
    }
  }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .my-component {
    &__image-container {
      &--img {
        display: none;
      }
    }
  }
}
</style>
```

When I try to do the unit test case and test if the image is hidden when the `window.width` is below `600px`, it doesn't update the DOM and the image is still visible:

```js
import MyComponentApp from './MyComponentApp.vue';
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils';

const factory = () => {
   return shallowMount(MyComponentApp, {});
};

describe('DownloadApp.vue', () => {
  let wrapper;

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = factory();
  });

  describe('Check Items on Mobile Devices', () => {  

    it('Img on div.my-component__image-container shouldn\'t be displayed', async () => {
      jest.spyOn(screen, 'height', 'get').mockReturnValue(500);
      jest.spyOn(screen, 'width', 'get').mockReturnValue(500);

      await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();
      const image = wrapper.find('div.my-component__image-container > img');
      expect(image.isVisible()).toBe(false);

    });
  });

});
```

However, the test fails:

```
DownloadApp.vue › Check Items on Mobile Devices › Img on div.my-component__image-container shouldn\'t be displayed

    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: false
    Received: true
```

Does anybody know how to update the DOM or make the test case realized that the screen width has changed and the image should be displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS `@media` queries depend on the *viewport size*, which currently cannot be manipulated from Jest alone, and setting `window.innerWidth` in Jest won't have an effect in this case.

Alternatively, you could resize the viewport in Cypress tests. In a Vue CLI project, you could add the [Cypress plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vue/cli-plugin-e2e-cypress) by running this command from the root of your project:

```
vue add e2e-cypress
```

Then in `<root>/tests/e2e/test.js`, insert the following tests that use [`cy.viewport()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/viewport.html) to set the viewport size before checking the `img` element's visibility:

```js
describe('My img component', () => {
  it('should show image for wide viewport', () => {
    cy.visit('/') // navigate to page where test component exists
    cy.viewport(800, 600)
    cy.get('.my-component__image-container--img').should('be.visible')
  })

  it('should hide image for narrow viewport', () => {
    cy.visit('/') // navigate to page where test component exists
    cy.viewport(500, 600)
    cy.get('.my-component__image-container--img').should('not.be.visible')
  })
})
```